# "Unable to install" on iOS with error "Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement" when compiling with xcode 14.2 xamarin.ios 16.0

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode14, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

We have an old school xamarin forms app that is being built using Azure DevOps. We were using the macOS-11 image for iOS builds which defaults to xcode 13.2.1 and xamarin.ios 15.4. But, Apple is now requiring apps submitted to the store be built with xcode 14.1 and iOS 16.1

[image: Apple Transporter Error]

That is fine we switched to macOS-12 to build with xcode 14.2 and ios 16.1 but now our app will not install ad hoc builds using the App Center portal. The app stops installing and we get an error that says:

> Unable to install "[App Name]" Please try again later.

The console device logs has the following error from the installd process:

> 0x16fccb000 -[MIInstallableBundle _validateApplicationIdentifierForNewBundleSigningInfo:error:]: 981: Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement.

I've tried adding the "application-identifier" to the entitlements plist but it hasn't made a difference.

```
<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
```

Has anyone run into this problem?

**UPDATE:** Just to keep this information up to date. My work around no longer works with having installed Xcode 15. Now it doesn't matter if I compile on DevOps or locally I still get the same install error. Since the announced retirement of AppCenter I set up our app in Runway and get the same exact problem. I have verified the application identifier in both the "app" file and the mobile provisioning profile.

In this image is the entitlements that are in the app package that is contained in the IPA file that I can see with codesign. I can see these entitlements if I compile with xcode 13.2.1 but there are no entitlements if I compile using xcode 14.2+. It just outputs nothing.

[image]

Comment: Still have this problem. Our solution was to just downgrade the xcode version during development and then during release testing I would create manual builds locally and upload them to App Center. We just recently Migrated the app to Maui and while testing the new azure build pipeline YAML file we discovered this problem all over again. This time building with macos-13 / xcode 15.0.1

Comment: With the recent news that AppCenter will go away March 2025 I decided to test out alternative ad-hoc distribution apps and set up a Runway account and uploaded our IPA to that site and I still get the Entitlement error, so I know it is not an AppCenter issue.